# Calculating the band structure of Bi2Se3 with spin-orbit coupling

Tags: vasp, band-structure, self-consistent-field, spin-orbit-coupling, brillouin-zone

I would like to simulate $\ce{Bi_2Se_3}$ using a DFT calculation on VASP. However, it seems I am not able to get a result; the electronic steps take $\sim \infty$ of time to complete. Here are the details of my input.

INCAR file:

```
System = bi2se3 soc calculation -- SCF

ISMEAR = 0
SIGMA = 0.2


EDIFF = 0.00000001

PREC = Accurate

LSORBIT = .TRUE.



NCORE = 16

ICHARG = 2


ENCUT = 500
```

KPOINTS file:

```
Automatic Mesh generation 
0
M
15 15 15
0 0 0
```

I am pretty sure the structure file is correct. However, I did not relax the bulk structures. I suspect the problem could be due to the density of the Brillouin zone grid mesh / the `ENCUT` parameter value, but I am not sure. How can I approach this problem? Currently, the calculation seems to be frozen even before the output shows the table of the electronic steps.

Comment: Hi ! have you tried using a smaller k point grid (say 7x7x7) and a lower cutoff close to the minimum requirement (specified in your pseudopotential files) so as to know whether the calculation actually runs. After that you could increase the k point grid and ECUT values so that it gives you a good enough accuracy for a reasonable computation time. It might be because your computational resources may not be able to handle a SOC calculation (which tend to be expensive) on a 15x15x15 grid. Im not an avid user of VASP, but these suggestions are from my experience in using Quantum ESPRESSO. :)

Comment: Hi Anoop. Thanks! I'm using 256 CPU cores to do this. I will try to reduce the ENCUT and the density of the k-grid and see what I can get. I

Comment: +1. Please look at my edit to see some small changes I made such as using ChemJax for the chemical formula and a `code` block for the input parameter.

Answer (score 4):

Here are some possible changes to your input that may resolve the problem:

1. Your `EDIFF` is very small; use the default and then increase precision from there.
2. Use a smaller `SIGMA`, start with 0.15 or 0.1.
3. Decrease the number of k-points, start with 5x5x5, then increase to reach the desired precision.

Good luck!